# Nginx will not load Flask static files

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

New flask/nginx/uWSGI server. Application loads and functions as expected but non of the html/css templates will load. Using developer tools in Chrome shows the pages are not being returned.

"tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log" says the file or directory does not exist. But it appears to be the correct path. Full path is "/opt/netmgmt/app/static/css/main.css"

```
2016/09/15 22:04:40 [error] 4939#0: *1 open() "/app/static/css/main.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.0.69, server: , request: "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1", host: "nms-srv2", referrer: "http://nms-srv2/"
```

Flask debugging shows no issue at all. 
Ive been banging my head against this one for a while and found multiple other threads with the same issue but nothing is solving this for me.

Thanks for the help!

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events {

worker_connections 1024;

}

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Configuration containing list of application servers
    upstream uwsgicluster {

        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        # ..
        # .

    }
    # Configuration for Nginx
    server {

        # Running port
        listen 80;

        # Settings to by-pass for static files
        location ^~ /static/  {

            # Example:
            # root /full/path/to/application/static/file/dir;
            root /app/;

        }

        # Serve a static file (ex. favico) outside static dir.
        location = /favico.ico  {

            root /app/favico.ico;

        }

        # Proxying connections to application servers
        location / {

            include            uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass         uwsgicluster;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        }
```

App file (Ive tried changing the static location multiple ways and using alias instead of root with no luck.)

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')
```

Layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>NetMgmt</title>
    <strong><link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"></strong>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">NetMgmt (beta)</h1>
        <strong><nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nginx configuration use an absolute path to your `static` directory. `static` should be in the path:

```
location ^~ /static/  {
    root /full/path/to/app/static/;
}
```

Comment: Using " root /opt/netmgmt/app/static/;" i get same error showing path "/opt/netmgmt/app/static/static/css/main.css. Using " root /opt/netmgmt/app/; " it works in IE but chrome/FF does not with error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain"

Comment: This link solved the mime type issue. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/css-files-not-interpreted-by-the-client-s-browser-i-think-my-nginx-config-is-not-good. Added "include    conf/mime.types;" to the http section and all is good. Thanks for them dude!!